# Limitation of local UserNotifications

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I studied on iOS local notification and my some of assumptions are:

1. We cannot schedule a notification with single identifier for **multiple distinct dates** or `dates:[Date]`
2. We cannot **get the notification instance** by any delegates (or anyway ) while **app is not running** and **user didn’t tapped** the notification
3. We cannot repeat a notification **to a given expire date**

Am I correct ?

Apple Documentation : [Link 1](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications)   [Link 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/index.html)

Comment: **1)** Doable and is related to 3. **2)** What do you mean by *"get the notification instance"*? **3)** Doable.

Comment: @Carpsen90 1) how to do that ? yes bit of related 2) to know that , a notification has just been showed or will be showed

Comment: Then the answer to **2)** is Doable.

Comment: @Carpsen90 I'm ready to set a accept mark with a upvote on your answer

Answer (score 1):

It is correct, local notifications are very limited, and are mostly used as immediate or next executions before an event occurred, to do what you say I recommend using push notifications, Firebase is one of the most popular currently and easy to manage, you could try with this [Firebase Cloud Messaging Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client?hl=es-419)